# Local CSS Not Loading on Flask Template

Tags: python, css, flask, jinja2

Hey I am trying to input custom css into my flask application. I was able to load bootstrap fine but when it comes to my local css I am having touble.

Here is how I am loading my css:

```css
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <link ref="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static',filename='styles/main_design.css') }}">
```

Comment: is your static folder at the same location as your .py file?

Comment: Yes I have my static folder in the same place as my .py. In fact i use the url_for function to load images in my static folder.

Comment: Try mentioning type="text/css” in your link tag

Comment: Tried that as well with no luck

Answer (score -1):

Maybe this is because your browser is not refreshing static files you can easily fix this by hot refreshing (**ctrl+refresh** or **ctrl+F5**)